# How a fread function work?

Tags: c

```
int main()

{


  char  buffer[100];
  fread(buffer,1,4,stdin);
  int i=0;
  while(i<4)

  {
    printf ("%c,\n",buffer[i]);

    i=i+1;
  }

 getch();

}
```

How the fread function will know,when to stop reading the input stream,what does the size and count elements signify,and how to manipulate size and count to get the maximum stream reading speed?

Comment: Please edit your question to state what you are trying to achieve and what the input and the expected output should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print all bytes in an `int`? Remember that an `int` is 32-bit, which is four bytes. Reading it into a `char` buffer makes it easier to access those four bytes in the `int`.

**Edit:** Little explanation of the `int` type...

Lets say you have an `int`:

```
int someIntValue = 0x12345678;
```

This is stored in 32 bits in the memory. As a single byte (`char`) is 8 bits, there are four bytes to an `int`. Each byte in the `int` can be accessed by using a `char` array or pointer:

```
char *someCharPointer = (char *) &someIntValue;
```

Now you can access those four separate bytes, and see their values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
    printf("someCharPointer[%d] = 0x%02x\n", i, someCharPointer[i]);
```

The above will print (on a little-endian machine such as x86):

```
someCharPointer[0] = 0x78
someCharPointer[1] = 0x56
someCharPointer[2] = 0x34
someCharPointer[3] = 0x12
```

If you now change `someIntValue` to the number `1`

```
someIntValue = 1;
```

and print it out again, you will see *this* result:

```
someCharPointer[0] = 0x00
someCharPointer[1] = 0x00
someCharPointer[2] = 0x00
someCharPointer[3] = 0x01
```

### Memory layout of an `int`

If you have a variable of type `int` stored in memory with the value `0x12345678`, it's stored like this:

```
   8 bits
,----^---.
|        |

+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|00111000|01010110|00110100|00010010|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+

|                                   |
`-----------------v-----------------'
                  |
               32 bits
```

This `int` is the same as the four bytes (or `char`) `0x78`, `0x56`, `0x34` and `0x12`.

However if we change the `int` to the number `1` then it's stored like this:

```
   8 bits
,----^---.
|        |

+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|00000000|00000000|00000000|00000001|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+

|                                   |
`-----------------v-----------------'
                  |
               32 bits
```

This `int` is the same as the four bytes (or `char`) `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x00` and `0x01`.

So now you hopefully can see how reading as an `int` and printing as `char` will display a different result from reading and `int` and printing it as an `int`.

Comment: when i am using int instead of char i am not getting the ans...?

Comment: @user1781308 `int` != `char`. Please tell what you want to do instead of just showing some piece of code and letting us guess. What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: i am just trying to figure out the use of fread function..to read data from stdin.

Comment: why i cannot use the 2nd program...it giving me uexpected values.

Comment: @user1781308 You told `fread` to read four bytes into `buffer`, but you're printing out four `int`s.

Comment: @user1781308 Added some explanation how `int` "works" and are stored in memory.

Comment: ok...i got it but why i am not getting the ans when using the int buffer[]

Comment: @user1781308 Again, `int` is **not** `char`. If you store the number `1` in an `int` it is stored in memory as the binary number `00000000000000000000000000000001`, if you store the same number `1` as a `char` it's stored in memory as `00000001`. As you can see there is a difference. Added this example to my answer.